# Pattern matching on function parameters

Tags: scala

I have a vector of tuples

```
val l = for {i <- 1 to 5} yield (i,i*2)
Vector((1,2), (2,4), (3,6), (4,8), (5,10))
```

and I'd like to sum it in the following way:

```
l.reduce((x,y) => (x._1+y._1, x._2+y._2))
(15,30)
```

but with use of pattern matching.

I know how to do it if the function gets only one parameter, ie: `l.map({case(a,b)=>a+b})`, but I can't get it to work with two parameters. this is what I tried to do:

```
l.reduce({(case(a,b),case(c,d))=>(a+c,b+d)})
```

but that won't work.

So my question is, how can I unpack 2 tuples that come as a function parameters?

Comment: `val (a, b) = l.unzip;(a.sum, b.sum)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just specify type explicitly to help partial functions mechanism:

```
l.reduce[(Int, Int)]{ case ((a,b), (c, d)) => (a + b, c + d)}
```

Without `[(Int, Int)]` scala can't infer correct type for your partial function

P.S. If you're intersesting why you see this error about `String` regardless what type you're actually using (it's `Int` in your case):

```
found   : Any , 
required: String
```

That's because of implicit "+" for strings in `Predef`. It's not the only problem with this implicit - you may look at [SI-194](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-194).

Even without that:

```
l.reduce{ case ((a,b), (c, d)) => (a, d)}

The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: (?, ?) => ?
```

scala was unable to infer the type, because it can't infer a type for partial function - may be any supertype of Int: `(A1, A1) => A1` expected, where `[A1 >: A]`

Comment: Nice. Can you explain why is the type required? I would say that compiler knows the type of l.

Comment: The type is specified as [A1 >: A] so scala infers Tuple2[Any, Any] for input, but Tuple2[String, String] for output, because of "+" operation (which is implicit for strings in Predef). Even without + type is uncknown - because pattern matching can't infer type - it don't know which superclass of Int to expect.

Comment: Using `fold` and providing the first parameter also works: `nums.fold(0 -> 0){ case ((a, b),(c, d)) => (a + c, b + d) }`

Comment: Yeah, because you're specifing type semi-explicitly in 0 -> 0, e.g. it's inferred type from first parameter

Answer (score 2):

You wrote something similar to partial function definition. I am not sure if that was your intention. This works:

```
l.reduce((x,y) => (x, y) match {
  case ((a,b), (c,d)) => (a+c, b+d)
})
```