# scala inline function - "ar.reduce((x,y) => x)" works but "ar.reduce{case(x,y) => x}" doesnt

Tags: scala, functional-programming

given the following input:

```
scala> val as = List(Array(1,2,3), Array(10,20,30), Array(100,200,300))
as: List[Array[Int]] = List(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(10, 20, 30), Array(100, 200, 300))
```

I am wondering why this works:

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
scala> as.reduce((x,y) => x)
res65: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

But this *seemly identical thing does not work*:

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
scala> as.reduce{case(x,y) => x}
<console>:13: error: missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: (?, ?) => ?
       as.reduce{case(x,y) => x}
```

Can anyone explain why the 1st example works but not the 2nd example?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12869583/1448212

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869251/the-argument-types-of-an-anonymous-function-must-be-fully-known-sls-8-5)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. They both run into the same error, but this question is asking why these two specific examples are different.

Comment: The referenced answer talks about that point

Comment: This question (mentioned below) seems closest to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240898/pattern-matching-on-function-parameters/26243303#26243303

Answer (score 2):

As the error message said, you need to specify type `Array[Int]`. This one will work:

```
as.reduce[Array[Int]]{ case (x,y) => x}
```

There is a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26243303/2507225).

Answer (score 1):

In Example 1, the argument to `reduce` is a Function2, taking two inputs (x and y) and returning x.

In Example 2, the argument to `reduce` is a Function1, taking one input, which happens to be a Tuple2, and returning the first element in the tuple.

The `reduce` method requires a Function2 as its argument, and so that's why Example 1 works, but Example 2 doesn't.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer since `val f2: Function2[Int, Int, Int] = {case(x,y) => x+y}` is valid